# how to populate input field when value of select is changed using Antd Form?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need to change the value of the input field to whatever value of the select field has changed.
If "Fire" is selected in the select field, then the input field needs to change to "Fire" as well.
This works when using the value in the input field and assigning the state of select to it.

**Working Code:**

```
const [type, setType] = React.useState("");

 <Select
          style={{
            width: 120
          }}
          onChange={(value) => setType(value)}
        >
          <Option value="fire">Fire</Option>
          <Option value="water">Water</Option>
          <Option value="wind">Wind</Option>
 </Select>
<Input
  style={{
    width: 120
  }}
  placeholder="Enter Type"
  value={type}
/>
```

The above code works, but using inside a `Form`, it doesn't.

**Code:**

```
const Demo = () => {
  const [type, setType] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <Form onFinish={onSubmit}>
      <Form.Item name="floorType">
        <Select
          style={{
            width: 120
          }}
          onChange={(value) => setType(value)}
        >
          <Option value="fire">Fire</Option>
          <Option value="water">Water</Option>
          <Option value="wind">Wind</Option>
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item name="floorName">
        <Input
          style={{
            width: 120
          }}
          placeholder="Enter Type"
          value={type}
        />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button
          type="primary"
          htmlType="submit"
          style={{
            width: 120
          }}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

The value isn't set in the input field.

*UI Library used :* Antd https://ant.design/components/form/

**Codesandbox link :** https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-21-6-forked-ckxgsy?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Fixed fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-form-fix-xtqz0o?file=/demo.js:266-299)

I based this fix on the [Antd Form > Form Methods](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-control-hooks) example, which shows how to update a form field when another one changes.

---

**The problem** seems to be you're using `Input`>`value` instead of letting the Antd Form handle the form state.

> The problem arises when adding `Form.Item`>`name`, because in this way the Form itself handles the child input value using a hidden state object where the keys are the `Form.Item` names and the initial values are the ones you can optionally define inside `Form`>`initialValues` prop.

> So, *if you want to avoid having the form manage the state*, you should also avoid using `Form.Item`>`name` prop and manage all form state yourself (but missing out on many of the advantages of the Antd form).
> ***In fact this should be avoided.***

---

##### Explanation of the fix

In the fork, the form manages the state, and the `setFieldsValue` method is used to update the `floorName` value (aka your `Input`).

*Changes*

- Removed the value prop from the input

  ```
  <Input
     style={{
       width: 120
     }}
     placeholder="Enter Type"
     // Remove the prop value from the input and let the form handle it
   />
  ```
- Add a form reference (using `Form.useForm`)

  ```
  const Demo = () => {
      // Get a form reference
      const [form] = Form.useForm();

      return (
       <Form
          form={form}
          ...
  ```
- Update the `Select` onChange using the form method `setFieldsValue` instead of the `setType` setter

  ```
  <Select
     style={{
       width: 120
     }}
     onChange={(value) => {
       // Set New Form Value for Form.Item > name = 'floorName'
       form.setFieldsValue({ floorName: value }); 
       // Using the Form.Item 'name' as object key when updating
     }}
   >
  ```

---

After all, the [Antd Form](https://ant.design/components/form/) is an

> High performance Form component ***with data scope management***

so you shouldn't try to handle the form state yourself (especially when `Form.Item`>`name` is specified for your fields).